# prequantization euclidiean space

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-numbers, quantum-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

In general  the prequantum hilbert space of some manifold $M$  will be the sections of the complex line bundle.  I ommitted a lot of details of course.
Locally, a section of a **complex** line bundle simply looks like a complex valued function. (of course the sections are square integrable).

However, for a euclidean space, we choose $L^{2}(R^{2n})$ as the prequantum hilbert space. But aren't these **real** square integrable functions? Why not complex any more.

Comment: Be careful whether your Hilbert space is real $L^2(X;\mathbb{R})$ or the hermitian $L^2(X;\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: well, I always see complex hermitian line bundles for constructing prequantum hilbert space. Isn't that usual? So that's basically my question. Should it be real or complex, and if complex, why are they inconsistent when it comes to euclidean space? Or am I missing something

Comment: I'm saying your $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ -- is it the space of square-integrable $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions mod a.e. equivalence, or $\mathbb{C}$-valued.  In this context we need to take $\mathbb{C}$-valued variant instead of the $\mathbb{R}$-valued variant, one reason being the Schrodinger equation needs the complex scalars.

Comment: Ah okay, then it should be complex valued. But aren't they automatically smooth as well?

Comment: No, $L^2$-functions can fail to have (classically) differentiable representatives, e.g., $1_{[0,1]}$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ but there are no representatives that are differentiable at $0$ or $1$.  What you have is that those representable by smooth functions are dense so every $L^2$ functions can be approximated by smooth functions.

Comment: But sections are always smooth right? and if u is a unit section, then a section s can be written as   f*u with f a smooth  Complex valued function. I thought that you want to collect this functions and only the square integrable ones of them.

Comment: The smooth square integrable sections form a pre-Hilbert space with respect to the $L^2$ norm (i.e., an inner product space that is not complete). The completion of this space is isometric to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{C})$, and can be thought of as the space of discontinuous sections of the line bundle.